# Set div to 100% of content

Tags: html, css, layout, grid

I am using the 1140px fluid grid (cssgrid.net) layout.

I am having some problem..

My layout looks like this:

```
Side Menu - Content
          - Content
          - Content
          - Content
          - etc. etc.
```

My problem is, that my layout does like this:

```
Side Menu - Content
Content
Content
Content
Content
etc. etc.
```

I want, so my "Side Menu" is full height, so it will push the content to "the right".

My layout (Exist of 12 cols):

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="twocol">
    -- Side Menu Content Here --
    </div><!-- END 2col --> 

    <div class="tencol last">
    content content content
    </div> 
    <div class="tencol last">
    content content content
    </div> 
    <div class="tencol last">
    content content content
    </div> 
    <div class="tencol last">
    content content content
    </div> 
  </div><!-- END .row -->  
</div><!-- END .container -->
```

The CSS is:

```
.container {
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}

.row {
width: 100%;
/*max-width: 1140px; */
min-width: 755px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

.onecol, .twocol, .threecol, .fourcol, .fivecol, .sixcol, .sevencol, .eightcol, .ninecol, .tencol, .elevencol {
margin-right: 3.8%;
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
}

.row .onecol {
width: 4.85%;
}

.row .twocol {
width: 13.45%;
}

.row .threecol {
width: 22.05%;
}

.row .fourcol {
width: 30.75%;
}

.row .fivecol {
width: 39.45%;
}

.row .sixcol {
width: 48%;
}

.row .sevencol {
width: 56.75%;
}

.row .eightcol {
width: 65.4%;
}

.row .ninecol {
width: 74.05%;
}

.row .tencol {
width: 82.7%;
}

.row .elevencol {
width: 91.35%;
}

.row .twelvecol {
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

.last {
margin-right: 0px;
}
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Just a tip: You might want to create a http://jsfiddle.net/. It's a nice tool when asking for help with any HTML tech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout looks this way:

```
body
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| two col content   ten col content                          |
| +--------------+ +---------------------------------------+ |
| |              | |                                       | |
| |              | |                                       | |
| +--------------+ +---------------------------------------+ |
| +---------------------------------------+                  |
| |   ten col content                     |                  |
| |                                       |                  |
| +---------------------------------------+                  |
| +---------------------------------------+                  |
| |   ten col content                     |                  |
| |                                       |                  |
| +---------------------------------------+                  |
| +---------------------------------------+                  |
| |   ten col content                     |                  |
| |                                       |                  |
| +---------------------------------------+                  |
| +---------------------------------------+                  |
| |   ten col content                     |                  |
| |                                       |                  |
| +---------------------------------------+                  |
| +---------------------------------------+                  |
| |   ten col content                     |                  |
| |                                       |                  |
| +---------------------------------------+                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Do not repeat that ten col content. Keep it as a wrapper and use smaller divs. Like this:

```
body
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| two col content   ten col content                          |
| +--------------+ +---------------------------------------+ |
| |              | | +-----------------------------------+ | |
| |              | | |                                   | | |
| +--------------+ | |                                   | | |
|                  | +-----------------------------------+ | |
|                  | +-----------------------------------+ | |
|                  | |                                   | | |
|                  | |                                   | | |
|                  | +-----------------------------------+ | |
|                  | +-----------------------------------+ | |
|                  | |                                   | | |
|                  | |                                   | | |
|                  | +-----------------------------------+ | |
|                  | +-----------------------------------+ | |
|                  | |                                   | | |
|                  | |                                   | | |
|                  | +-----------------------------------+ | |
|                  | +-----------------------------------+ | |
|                  | |                                   | | |
|                  | |                                   | | |
|                  | +-----------------------------------+ | |
|                  +---------------------------------------+ |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In case if you want the HTML Code,

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="twocol">
        -- Side Menu Content Here --
        </div><!-- END 2col --> 

        <div class="tencol last">
            <div>
                content content content
            </div>
            <div>
                content content content
            </div>
            <div>
                content content content
            </div>
            <div>
                content content content
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div><!-- END .row -->  
</div><!-- END .container -->
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `height: 100%` to the menu-div (twocol). That should do it.

In any way: maybe it would be a bit better to change the structure of the divs a bit:

```
<div class="menu">
-- Side Menu Content Here --
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="tencol last">
    content content content
    </div> 
    <div class="tencol last">
    content content content
    </div> 
    <div class="tencol last">
    content content content
    </div> 
    <div class="tencol last">
    content content content
    </div> 
</div>
```

I my experience it makes the layouting easier, when you have seperate divs containing the menu, content, header and footer.

When you use float, I often set a backgroudcolor to my divs during development, so I can see how much space they take (especially the height). Because as soon as the div ends, all left floated divs will go as far left as they can.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it here on jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/cXXGj/ ). I think you need this way. I just wrapped content inside another div with class content_container. Have a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cXXGj/